# Getting the environment of a process running under a different user

Tags: c, linux

Assume I have a process with PID 1234 running in the background under user A.

If I run the following program as user A, it succeeds. If I run it as user B, it fails with `open: Permission denied`.

This makes sense, as the `environ` file is owned by user A and has read permission only for A. 
But if I make the program set-user-ID for user A and run it as user B, it fails with `read: Permission denied`. This doesn't seem to happen with a regular file having the same permissions. It also doesn't happen if A is root.

Any ideas why? Is there any other way to get the environment of another process that works around this issue?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    unsigned char ch = 0;
    int fd = -1;
    int read_result = -1;

    setresuid(geteuid(), geteuid(), geteuid());

    fd = open("/proc/1234/environ", O_RDONLY);
    if (-1 == fd) {
        perror("open");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    read_result = read(fd, &ch, 1);
    if (-1 == read_result) {
        perror("read");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    close(fd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see, if your program run **without** SETUID, open(2) gives you `Permission denied`, whereas if you run the program **with** SETUID, open(2) works ok, but read(2) causes the same error. This happens because of additional permission check during each file operation on `/proc/*` inodes. Looks like this additional permission check uses something other than EUID of the running process. If you run GNU/Linux, for more details see **NOTE** at the beginning of the code in `<kernel_source>/fs/proc/base.c` and environ_read() function in the same file.

One of the possible quick solutions:

- set owner of the program file to `root`
- set owner group to some special group
- add user that should run the program (user B) to that special group
- set mode bits to 4550 (r-sr-x---)
- call `setuid(getuid())` to drop priveleges as soon as possible, i.e. right after reading `environ` file

In this case any user from the given group could read `/proc/*/environ` of **any** other user.

If you want to reduce the permissions of your program to allow only read `environ` files of the specific user (user A), you probably should think of some other tricks. For example config file, containing the user(s) whose `environ` file(s) could be read.

Always be careful with extra permissions. Especially with *root* permissions. Do necessary privileged operations and drop permissions as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you. I looked at the code you mentioned. It eventually calls ptrace_may_access(task, PTRACE_MODE_READ) which checks the gid/egid/sgid of the process in addition to the uid,suid and euid. Giving the executable setgid and adding a setresgid call solved my problem.